# Cant calculate percentage difference between two numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to show the percentage after a number is subtracted.

Example:

Cost of work = `£165.00`
Workers charge = `£42.00`
Left Over = `%`

What is the percentage of Cost left after the worker has got his cut.

My Code output is showing 0

```
int number = 0, number1, result = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice, out number) && Int32.TryParse(Rate.Content.ToString().ToString(), out number1))
 {result = number - number1;}
 JobPercentage.Content = result.ToString();
```

Comment: (165 - 42)  / 165 = 0.745 or 74.5%

Comment: Not sure how you would get a percentage out of a subtraction equation. Today would be a good day to learn the debugger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple formula is `PART / MAX * 100`

In your fault It should look like this:

```
double costOfWork = 165;
double workersCharge = 42;

double left = Math.Round((costOfWork - workersCharge) / costOfWork * 100, 2);
```

It calculates the remaining cost using `costOfWork - workersCharge`.

Then it calculates how many percents the remaining cost is.
It's getting rounded to two digits.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the issue in C#- FileComparison
`double size = (LengthOfTxt-LengthOfDocx) / LengthOfDocx / 100;`